# Image classifier “ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.”

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have this problem when I try to run this code using 3 folders of dataset. Previously, this code ran perfectly with only 2 folders inside the dataset folder, one called `normal`, the other `covid`. But in this case I added another one called `pneumonia` to make it a 3 category image classifier. I'm new in machine learning, so I investigated a lot about how to fix this, but every solution is different and also the code. I tried them but they didn't work, that's the reason why I'm asking for your help.

This code doesn't belong to me, it's an Adrian Rosebrock code, all the credit goes to him. It's about classifying X-ray images in COVID or normal cases, but the idea to improve this code add a new category to classify images with normal (non-COVID) pneumonia. That's why I added a new folder into the dataset. Hope you can help me, thanks!

```
# USAGE
python train.py --dataset dataset
```

```py
# import the necessary packages

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from imutils import paths

import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output loss/accuracy plot")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str, default="covid19.model",
    help="path to output loss/accuracy plot")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the initial learning rate, number of epochs to train for,
# and batch size

INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 1
BS = 8

# grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
# the list of data (i.e., images) and class images

print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))
data = []
labels = []

# loop over the image paths

for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    # load the image, swap color channels, and resize it to be a fixed
    # 224x224 pixels while ignoring aspect ratio
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image,(224, 224))

    # update the data and labels lists, respectively
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)

# convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays while scaling the pixel
# intensities to the range [0, 255]

data = np.array(data) / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

# perform one-hot encoding on the labels

lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)
```

This is the error message:

```
[INFO] loading images...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_covid19.py", line 77, in <module>
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)
  File "C:\Users\KQ\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2143, in train_test_split
    train, test = next(cv.split(X=arrays[0], y=stratify))
  File "C:\Users\KQ\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 1737, in split
    y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
  File "C:\Users\KQ\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 574, in check_array
    % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Comment: Code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and should **not** be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter. Code posted here should be minimal & only related to the error - please see why [a wall of code isn't helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need both `LabelBinarizer` and `to_categorical`. They do the same thing, so you only need one or the other. Try removing the call to `to_categorical`.

```py
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)  # Remove this line.
```

You will also need to update the number of categories in your model.

```py
# Change the size from 2 to 3.
headModel = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(headModel)
```

To avoid the need to change this every time you add or remove categories, you could count the unique labels.

```py
n_labels = len(set(labels))
headModel = Dense(n_labels, activation="softmax")(headModel)
```

**Update**

Also note that `to_categorical` will only work on integer labels. That makes it more like [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.htmlhttps://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) than [LabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html).

Here is what it looks like to call everything.

```py
labels = [0, 1, 0, 2]                                                                                                                                                                                                               

lb = LabelBinarizer() 
binarized = lb.fit_transform(labels)                                                                                                                                                                                                
binarized                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# array([[1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1]])

to_categorical(labels)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
# array([[1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 0.],
#        [1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)

to_categorical(binarized)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# array([[[0., 1.],
#         [1., 0.],
#         [1., 0.]],
# 
#        [[1., 0.],
#         [0., 1.],
#         [1., 0.]],
# 
#        [[0., 1.],
#         [1., 0.],
#         [1., 0.]],
# 
#        [[1., 0.],
#         [1., 0.],
#         [0., 1.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Note the 3-dimensional output for the labels, as it tries to one-hot encode each of the 3 parts of the already one-hot encoded data, adding an additional dimension that `train_test_split` does not know how to handle.

That is why you got a `ValueError: Found array with dim 3.`

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works perfectly, i could run the code, i changed the settings as your instructions,but the n_labels to avoid the changes of categories didn´t worked. I put 3 manually but then i had an issue with `UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predict
ed samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.` obtaining a 0 value of predictions in my first two categories, i read it´s  because y_test and x_test are empty with examples of the other categories, but the the folders have images, any idea of this ?

Comment: That is a mistake on my part. You would need to compute `n_labels` before encoding, or change to `n_labels = labels.shape[1]`. As for the new warning, that is appearing because, as you say, some of your labels do not have any examples in the test set. You do not have enough samples per class to do the train-test split. Perhaps your new `pneumonia` data set only has 1 or very few examples? Adding more should solve the problem.

Comment: I tried it, at the begining the folder of covid and normal had 25 images inside, and the pneumonia folder 68 images, EPOCHS =1, those were the variables, then i tried reducing the number of images of pneumonia folder to 28 images and obtained an acc number to covid category (now 2 categories have values of acc). I tried again increasing the number of EPOCHS to 10 and finally obtain acc values for the 3 categories, one with 1.00 of precission, the second with 0.2, and the last one 0.5. I suppose it´s an epochs and number of images issues, is it true ? thanks for your help again

Comment: I believe this may also happen if your model does not ever predict some label. This is why changing the model training details matters, because it also changes the predictions and therefore whether or not this happens.